# Why can't we just multiply by the inverse of K in the equation of the eigenvalue problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What happens if we multiply by $K^{-1}$ from the left in $$A k = \lambda k $$? , a little back story:
Was trying to find a simpler way to prove that $P(A)K=P(\lambda)K$ and then thought of doing what I asked about in the title until I arrived at $P(A)=P(\lambda)$ which is what I though of as the statement of Cayley-Hamilton, now I know that it should be only applied to the characteristic equation so I'm lost now...

Comment: $k$ is a vector (not a square, invertible matrix)

Comment: If $A$ is an invertible matrix and if $\lambda$ is a (necessarily  nonzero) eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $x$ then indeed $(1/\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. Hence,  $A^{-k}x = (1/\lambda)^kx$ for all positive integers $k$. This means $A^n x = \lambda^n x$ for all integers $n$ (including negative integers).

Comment: @Michael thank you for your efforts, but that's not what I'm looking for, $P$ here is a polynomial.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I don't actually know how did I miss this, thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @user4155 There is no $P$ in your question.  In fact none of the quantities in the equation $Ak = \lambda k$ were defined, one can only guess this is intended to be an eigenvalue equation with matrix $A$, eigenvalue $\lambda$, eigenvector $k$. There was no $K$ defined and thus no $K^{-1}$, the only thing in sight that might be invertible was $A$ and so I assumed you meant $A^{-1}$. Indeed multiplying $A k = \lambda k$ on the left by $A^{-1}$ (when it exists) gives $k = \lambda A^{-1}k$, meaning $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in $$AK=\lambda K$$ K is a vector not a matrix so we can not find $K^{-1}$ so we have to solve for the non-zero vector $K$ to satisfy  $$AK=\lambda K$$

Secondly you mentioned that $$P(A)=P(\lambda)$$ and that is not the case because $P(A)$ is a matrix and $P(\lambda) $ is a polynomial. The Cayley- Hamilton theorem  is about $P(A)=0$ for the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ not the equality $P(A)=P(\lambda)$ which have different dimensions.

Comment: It makes sense now, also  $$P(A)=P(\lambda)=0$$ is what first came to my mind but I understand that it's not correct because of the unequal dimensions, Cayley-Hamilton only states that the matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation. So all in all thank you :)

Comment: @user4155 Thanks for your attention and understanding.